# Calling global function inside a CUDA Kernel

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to write a CUDA kernel function that contains Matrix multiplication, like:

```
__device__ Matrix_Multi(Matrix A,Matrix B,Matrix C);

 __global__ void foo(type para){
       ....
       Matrix_Multi(Matrix A,Matrix B,Matrix C);
       ....
}
```

I want to accelerate the matrix multiplication operation. I have two choices:

first, using *Cublas* library.
Second, write a kernel for matrix multiplication and call it inside `foo()`.

I failed in both cases.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you not write your own mat-mul kernel at this time. Try the cublas way.

cublas lib can only be called in the kernel for devices with compute capability at least equal to 3.5. otherwise it can only be called from the host side. you could check your cc version before using cublas lib.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But I have to do the matrix_multi operation inside the kernel. Do you know how can I achieve that?

Comment: One of my questions has a square-matrix-matrix multiplications by 32x32 patches if you are desperate. You can make other sized matrices fit to a square one by padding. 48x48 version uses %50 of gpu compute power.

Comment: @user2223969 but its opencl so you may need to convert to cuda :)

Comment: @Eric: CUBLAS also has a device library for compute capability 3.5 devices

Comment: @talonmies thanks for pointing out that. I've modified the answer.

Comment: Yes, but my device only has 2.0 compute ability.So I have to drop this method. Thanks.